# Angular 2 | How to set style to dynamic component style according to parent creating the component?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have the following HTML:

```
  <ul infraTooltip toolTipOptions="{check: 1}">
```

I have created a directive, which on its host is loading a dynamic component:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[infraTooltip]'
})
export class InfraTooltipDirective {
  @Input() toolTipOptions: any =  {};

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private viewContainerRef : ViewContainerRef ) {
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event', '$target'])
  showTooltip ($event) {
    this.loadContainerComponent();
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event', '$target'])
  hideTooltip ($event) {
    this.clearContainerComponent();
  }

  loadContainerComponent () {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipContainerComponent);
    let componentInstance =  this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    componentInstance.instance.toolTipOptions = this.toolTipOptions;
  }
```

I want to style my dynamic component according to the **host of the directive** - in my case, the **ul**, in order to achieve something like having my dynamic component left: 10px from the **ul**.

Comment: in you parent component, use `:host /deep/ tooltip(DynamicComponent selector name) {padding-left:10px}` better to provide different use cases along with plunkr.

Comment: @micronyks that means that every component that uses my directive(tooltip) needs to style it again and again(correct me if I am wrong). Is there any other option?

Comment: There are two ways. First way 1) from parent, pass styles(means object containing diff values) to directive/dynamiccomponent and bind it using `ngStyle` . 2) Simply styles the dynamic component from the parent using static styles as mentioned earlier.

Comment: What do you mean by "according to the host of the directive"? Why don't you just add `left: 10px` to the dynamic component?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
})
class TooltipContainerComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.left.px')
  left:number = 0;
}
```

```
  loadContainerComponent () {
    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipContainerComponent);
    let componentInstance =  this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    componentInstance.instance.toolTipOptions = this.toolTipOptions;
    componentInstance.instance.left = 10;
  }
```

Comment: Very informative!! Specially the style.left.px :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism is called View Encapsulation. You can read more it in [Angular documentation on View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html).

There are two possible solutions for the parent component to style the child component.

1. Turn off View Encapsulation in the child component
2. Use `/deep/` selector in your CSS.